# How will Gon continue fighting after his fight with Neferpitou?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

During the Chimera Ants Arc, after Gon fights with Neferpitou,

> Gon lost his Nen.

Will he be able to fight and continue advancing within the Hunter x Hunter Universe?

Comment: I suggest picking up the manga, it would answer your question.

Comment: hopefully with alluka reviving him from that state it also cured him of the condition of never using nen again

Answer (score 1):

Without nen, Gon won't be able to fight against Nen users. As was seen in the Heaven's Arena arc, the only way to defend against Nen is with Nen, and without it even relatively weak attacks will kill or cripple you.

At the moment, the story is on an indefinite hiatus, but if it ever gets going properly again, Gon will not be able to fight against Nen users unless somehow he is able to regain his Nen, whether by himself or by someone helping him.

It's obviously a different story, but I think it's similar to how after Ichigo lost his spiritual pressure in Bleach, he was pretty weak for a while until it was restored to him.

Alluka was able to save Gon, and it's definitely possible that either some Hunter has the capability to restore Gon's Nen, or that somewhere in the Dark Continent there will be a way of restoring it.

Comment: Did the manga specifically say that Gon couldn't relearn nen after he had lost it? If so, although it would set him back, he could regain his power. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about it deeply, Gon really didn't lose his Nen per se.
He just lost the ability to "use" it. Remember what Killua wished for? 
He wished Gon to return *back to normal*. But what is normal?

It is heavily implied that Gon's Nen pores are just back to normal again.
Even his dad had said, that he became "*normal*" and whether he wants to or
not is up to him.

Gon just has to re-learn Nen again, the way Wing forcefully opened his Nen pores or the natural way.

The main problem here is the wish. That aura spread too far and that wish is 
too powerful. I wonder who's gonna suffer.... ;)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Shan Coralde, that Killua was just dumb about the command he gave nanika, and should have been smarter about it, as returning gon to normal would mean normal like everyone else. Normal could also be implied as not having the same potential and growth rate he previously had, as that was extremely unnatural

Answer (score -1):

I think Gon will end up tracking down and joining the Phantom Troupe in order to regain the ability to use nen again. Also his nen category will probably change in the process. He may end up becoming a Conjurer or a Specialist.

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga Stack Exchange, a Q&A site related to anime & manga. We appreciate your contribution, but pure opinion/speculation answer is discouraged. Instead, please [edit] and try to back up the answer by providing supporting sources/references. Thank you.